# realtime graph android for iperf application

Tags: java, android, html5-canvas, achartengine

Hi I have developed IPerf application for android which gives throughput and time on the phone's screen. But I want a Throughput Vs Time graph on screen.
I am new to android. So please tell me how to do this.??

Answer (score 0):

look at my [Answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15893444/1752560) it might help u ::

U can change `getnext()` method as per ur requirement, may be as below::

```
public String getnext(int a)
{
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int mMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    int mHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int am =c.get(Calendar.AM_PM); 
    String ap;
    if(am==1)
    {ap="PM";}
    else {ap="AM";}
    String s = mHour+""+ap; // or String s = mHour+""+mMinute;
    return (s);
}
```