# Android - How can i align the y labels with their points?

Tags: android, graph, achartengine

i am using achartengine to draw a graph, but i don't know how to align the x labels with the relative points in the graph. To add Y labels i use this method:

```
    private void addSampleData() {
    int i=0;
    for(i=0; i<count; i++){
        mCurrentSeries.add(i+1, list_peso[i]);
        mCurrentSeries2.add(i+1, list_peso_ideale[i]);
        list_peso_string[i] = Double.toString(list_peso[i]);
        mRenderer.addXTextLabel(i+1, list_data[i]);
        mRenderer.addYTextLabel(i+1, list_peso_string[i]);
    }
```

it works for the Y labels, but not for the X labels. How van i do?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I dont understand why you are using `i+1` in `mRenderer.addYTextLabel(i+1, list_peso_string[i]);` 
instead just use `i` it may solve your problem

and if u want custom lablels:::

suppose ur custom x-axis labels should be :`private String[] mMonth = new String[] {
            "Jan", "Feb" , "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun",
            "Jul", "Aug" , "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"
        };`

so by using following loop can get [graph as shown in this graph](http://i49.tinypic.com/2j5xhrs.png)

```
int[] x = { 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7 };
for(int i=0; i< x.length;i++){
    multiRenderer.addXTextLabel(i, mMonth[i]);          
}
```

[And take look at this Question and my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15738648/1752560)

Comment: thx for the answer, by the way my X labels are ok, i mean that i have strings on the X labels, the problem is that i can't do the same with Y axis and i don't know why.

Comment: u want to display strings on y axis ?